# Can we create any Stored Procedure Identity changes as per date changes in MS SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can we create any stored procedure like below example in SQL Server 2008?

I have a table :

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
   ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   FirstName varchar(50)
)
```

Here if I insert any data then `ID` is automatically incremented by 1.

Like on 22/01/2014, I have inserted data like

Employee

```
1   Hank    Kent
2   Kent    Hank
```

But I'm looking is if system date changes then for next day that identity again start from 1 to increment.

Ex. on 23/01/2014 if insert any data then should look like

Previous table value and

```
1   John    Bat 
2   Debbi   Meera
```

Comment: You'll need a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) for that, I think.  It won't be an Identity field; Identity fields are "no duplicates," and your scheme will create duplicates.

Comment: You can't do this with your current table. The primary key has to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have duplicate values in the `ID` column as it is your primary key.  You can, however, build logic into a trigger or other constraint to set an additional field, maybe call it `DailyInsertOrder`, that updates itself on insert.

For example, you could create a default constraint on the `DailyInsertOrder` that calls a UDF function to find what "place" the record is in insertion.  This would also require you to save the date in which records were created, maybe in a datetime2 `CreatedDate` field.  Now you're burying business logic into your table schema, and, in my opinion, this is a bad practice.

Instead, just have a `CreateDate` field that defaults to `SYSDATETIME()` or is set with an `INSERT` trigger.  Then you can query using a ranking `SELECT` statement that groups by `CAST(CreateDate as date)`.

I can explain further if that does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

As per given scenario I think through hard code it's better way to do then i have done it in Java language.